# Force of Gravity on earth

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth

If you were to remove all the water from the Mariana trench would you experience more g's at the bottom of the Mariana trench or at the top of mount Everest?

Comment: To first order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem . There is, of course, the fact that Earth is not completely homogeneous. One of the effects of the shell theorem is that you wouldn't even have to remove the water in the trench. It has no gravitational effect on you to begin with (again with the caveat that the Earth is not homogeneously covered in water).

Comment: What is meant by remove all water from the Mariana trench? You mean remove and seal it so it won't overflow from the ocean? Otherwise if you drain the entire ocean that's a big difference... The mass of the water within the Mariana trench alone is *only* of order $10^{18} \text{ kg}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(volume)) compared with the entire earth which is of order $10^{24} \text{ kg}$ that won't do much to gravity.

Answer (score 1):

NASA mapped the gravity across the surface of Earth. You can see the map [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth).

As you can see on the map, the gravity at Mt Everest is notably stronger than the gravity at the Mariana trench. Draining the Mariana trench won't change that.

Comment: weaker, right? :)

Comment: Yes, I believe draining the Mariana trench would result in weaker gravity there. Between having less mass directly below you, and applying the shell theorem, I see no reason to expect that it should increase. Certainly not enough to surpass the strength of gravity at Mt Everest.

Comment: I was sure that the peak of mt. Everest must have weaker gravity... since it is farther away from the earth's center.

Comment: That's a reasonable guess, but it seems the mass of the mountains more than makes up for the additional distance. I'm going to go with NASA's data over intuition.

Comment: Ah, see I couldn't find the data you were referring to, it is just a link to Wikipedia, if you can give a more direct one that'll be great. Also, yes I do understand that in the Mariana trench also there is less mass below you so applying Gauss's law results in a weaker gravity field. It's really hard to intuitively grasp that these are small differences in comparison to the earth's radius which is why things like density, etc. really become important, and the difference won't be too big anyway :)

Comment: I'm referring to the map at the top of the Wikipedia page. That's the visualization of NASA's data. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/Gravity_anomalies_on_Earth.jpg

Comment: I see. Well, such visualization can be misleading, it might just be that if we actually check the measurements both locations may currently have about the same $g$ :)

Comment: Well, feel free to search around for the data sheet (it should be freely available somewhere), but I think the visualization is pretty clear on this.

Comment: WolframAlpha enables access to the Mathematica package [GeogravityModelData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeogravityModelData.html). I couldn't find out how this data is obtained, but it gives values of $g=9.76467 \text{ m/s}^2$ for [Mt Everest](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gravitational+acceleration+%5B%2F%2Fplace%3Aeverest%2F%2F%5D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22everest%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Mountain%22%7D), for [Mariana Trench](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=gravitational+acceleration+%5B%2F%2Fplace%3Amariana+trench%2F%2F%5D)$g=9.78213 \text{ m/s}^2$.

Comment: ... possible explanation: Reading [this](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/GRACE/page3.php) I see: "*Gravity anomaly maps (see globe below) show how much the Earth’s actual gravity field differs from the gravity field of a uniform, featureless Earth surface*" -- it may be that the red region merely indicates how much stronger the gravity on the Everest is compared with its *predicted* value due to height, and assuming a uniform mass distribution. It may *not* be an indication of the absolute field value at this region.

Comment: Uniform and featureless means assuming a perfectly spherical Earth that is perfectly smooth. The map isn't showing deviation from height, they're showing deviation from that global average value. That is, this can be used to exemplify absolute field value at that region.

Comment: Right... OTOH it's an oblate spheroid that supposedly is the smooth model for the earth, and it's beyond me how that would affect the expected value for the Mariana trench vs. mt. Everest, Mariana trench being quite a distance closer to the equator... :)

Comment: Some more interesting info I found: Using the [International gravity formula](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100007626) I calculated the expected $g$ at Everest's and Mariana trench latitudes. I got $g_{everest} = 9.791725 \text{ m/s}^2$ and $g_{mariana} = 9.782324 \text{ m/s}^2$. So assuming NASA uses at least a simple model as this the reference level isn't the same. Second, note this map shows deviations of no more than $\pm 50 \text { milligals}$ and $50 \text{ milligal} = 0.0005 \text{ m/s}^2$...

Comment: Considering this, I suspect all this map can really tell us is that at Mt. Everest gravity is slightly stronger than expected, indeed due to the massive mountain landmass, (and possibly that gravity at Mariana trench is weaker because it is at a much lower point on earth with respect to this latitude, but that isn't as visible on the map as Mt. Everest is...)